# long long Number div error

Tags: ios, html, converters

```
long long d = 1000*3600*24*365;
NSLog(@"d:%lld",d);

NSLog(@"year:%d",d/(1000*3600*24*365));

d = 100*1000*3600*24*365;
NSLog(@"year:%d",d/(1000*3600*24*365));
```

the result:

```
usworldpro[1106:c203] year:1

usworldpro[1106:c203] year:0
```

Why is this the result?
I think it may be a type conversion problem, but I can't clearly find the reason. Who can explain it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your literals are integers (int), not long long integers, and so each intermediate result is.
Try:

```
     long long d = 1000ll*3600ll*24ll*365ll;
     NSLog(@"d:%lld",d);

     NSLog(@"year:%d",d/(1000ll*3600ll*24ll*365ll));

     d = 100ll*1000ll*3600ll*24ll*365ll;
     NSLog(@"year:%d",d/(1000ll*3600ll*24ll*365ll));
```

However, telling `NSLog` or `printf` etc. the wrong format is always a bad idea.